# can't get data of a specific row with angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm building a project with angular and php. I have a customer table and I can retrieve all table data, but when I enter a specific customer it won't shows me his details. can someone help please?

customerCardDetailsCtrl.js -

```
"use strict";
angular.module('dataSystem').controller('customerCardDetailsCtrl', function($scope, $http ,$routeParams, $location) {

  var customer_id = $routeParams.customer_id;
  $scope.customer_id = customer_id;


  $http.get('http://localhost:8081/hamatkin/api/get-allCustomers.php/'+ customer_id).success(function(data){
    $scope.customerDetail = data;
  });
});
```

customerCardDetails.html - html page that show only customer_id

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="customer">
    <h1>כרטיס לקוח</h1>
    <a href="/hamatkin/index.html#/customerCards">חזור לרשימת כרטיסי הלקוחות</a>
    <h1 ng-bind="customerDetail.customer_id"></h1> 
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js -

```
 .when('/customerCardDetails/:customer_id', {
                controller: "customerCardDetailsCtrl",
                templateUrl: '../hamatkin/Views/customerCardDetails.html',
                screenTitle: "",
                costumerHidden: false,
                reportsHidden: true,
                stockHidden: true,
                isIncome_expensesHidden: true,
                isNavTabHidden: false,
                isFooterHidden: false,
                ordersHidden: true
```

Comment: *"won't shows me his details"* is far too vague for a problem description. Does route work? Does `$http` request work? Need to narrow issue down more

Comment: Also wondering why template is a full html page

Comment: @charlietfl trying to get details of a specific row. the $http and route are working. i have a html page that shows all table data. now i want to enter a specific to a specific customer and see in a new html page his details

Comment: what do you mean new html page? Is this not a single page app?

Comment: @charlietfl yes but you still have other html pages.

Comment: you are not helping isolate what is or isn't working on the route shown in question. Suggest reading [ask]